# R library folder location and Docker

Tags: r, docker, tidyverse, r-package

I am having an issue locating my R libraries in my linux instance.
I am installing rocker/tidyverse docker image and using a Dockerfile.
When doing `docker-compose up`, it says:

> Installing packages into '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library'

But after the installation, when I do `cd /usr/local/lib/` and `ls` I see absolutely no file.
Do you know what is wrong?

Comment: Are you persisting your Docker container?  Did you check with the running container that the installation of the package was successful during the Docker container lifetime?

Comment: yes volumes are persistent. And yes I can call the packages installed doing `library('package_name')`

Answer (score 0):

I believe its a permission issue

add yourself to the group called 'staff'

```
sudo usermod -a -G staff your_user_name
```

replace your_user_name with your login username

https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker/issues/207

or use the other way around

https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker/wiki/Sharing-files-with-host-machine#linux

or you can make the directory on docker command and give it write permission

```
mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/R/site-library 
chmod 777 /usr/local/lib/R/site-library
```

Comment: When I run this command I get: `usermod: group 'staff' does not exist`  Indeed, I ran `sudo vim /etc/group` and do not see any `staff` mentionned.

Comment: are you running this inside your container?

Comment: my bad I was not. Now I just did `docker exec -it <container_id> sudo usermod -a -G staff myusername` but I get: _usermod: user 'myusername' does not exist_ The login myusername is the one I use to log in RStudio.

Comment: this need to be added in the user conf not in the docker, however, if you want to add it to the docker as you are trying above, I will edit the answer

Comment: Sorry I'm still learning docker, when you say the user conf do you mean somewhere inside the `docker-compose.yml` ?

Comment: I just did `sudo groupadd staff` and then `sudo usermod -a -G staff ec2-user` worked. Let me relaunch and update my answer

Comment: I just rebuild the image and relaunched the docker image but still nothing in `cd /usr/local/lib/`